# how to set localstorage variable into a function

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this function

```
function sumFood (tot,tab_cout){
    var tot = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<tab_cout.length;i++) { 
        tot += Number(tab_cout[i]);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('tot',tot);
}

sumFood (GLC,GLCT); 
sumFood (LIP,LIPT);
```

I would like that GLC, LIP go into localStorage (in place of tot) but for some reasons the result I get is undefined... what to do? (console.log gives me good result of tot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you got undefined is you have hardcoded the `key` this line:

```
localStorage.setItem('tot',tot);
```

where it should be dynamically changed upon the parameters. Another thing you should be aware of is, it's not a good practice to name a variable inside a function the same as its parameter which is confusing. Try this:

```
function sumFood (tot,tab_cout){
  var total = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<tab_cout.length;i++) {total += Number(tab_cout[i]);}
  localStorage.setItem(`${tot}`,total);
}

sumFood(GLC,GLCT); 
sumFood(LIP,LIPT);
```

This will save the sum in seperate keys in localStorage. In your case, I'm assuming that you want to store all the key and value pairs in only one key, which is `tot` in the localStorage, then the `tot` has to be an `array of objects`. Try this below:

```
function sumFood (tot,tab_cout){
  let total = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<tab_cout.length;i++) {
    total += Number(tab_cout[i])
  }
  const savedTot = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tot')) || []
  const addedTot = savedTot.push({ [`${tot}`]: total })
  localStorage.setItem('tot', JSON.stringify(addedTot))
}

sumFood(GLC,GLCT)
sumFood(LIP,LIPT)
```

// if `GLC` and `LIP` are variables, otherwise you should put them in string. Like this:

```
sumFood('GLC',GLCT)
sumFood('LIP',LIPT)
```

Then retrieve it later:

```
const getTot = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tot')) || []
console.log(getTot) // you will see your expected output
```

Comment: GLC LIP are still undefined :( ... 
$ is not for jquery use?

Comment: What I would like to do ,  is to sum the element in an array for each items. when I enter the array GLCT I get the sum result GLC that I need  for others things; the same with LIPT etc. I thought if I put these items in localstorage each time, I will have a list of value

Comment: `${}` this is the Javascript template literals. You can look it up for future use. What do you mean by `GLC LIP` are undefined? How did you check that? I have added a few more lines in my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help; what helped me is that I shouldn't had to get the same word for key and variable for localStorage. But it works fine now, simply in the solution I gonna get below

Answer (score 0):

I had to put **return** total to get what I needed, and I don't need to store. So I guess your solution is correct for the entitled

```
 function sumFood (tot,tab_cout){
        var total = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<tab_cout.length;i++) { 
            total += Number(tab_cout[i]);
        }
    return total; 
     
    }
    
    sumFood (GLC,GLCT); 
    sumFood (LIP,LIPT);
```

Comment: The line after `return` won't execute, so this will return the value but won't actually set anything to localStorage. I think you're mixing up the values the console displays with what's actually getting stored.

Comment: you are right... I was mixing up. I don't need to store. gonna correct it